# How to add and update values in objects using Realm (Swift)?

Tags: swift, realm

I have two classes given below. I want to perform operations like (Add, Update and Delete) to these objects.

Class *CheckOutImageList* is an array of object that contains images and Class *CheckOutDetail* is an object that contains image object.

```
class CheckOutImageList: Object {

    @objc dynamic var imageUrl = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageName = "test"
    @objc dynamic var isProfile = Bool()
    @objc dynamic var imageDesc = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "imageName"
    }
}

class CheckOutDetail: Object {

    @objc dynamic var taskId = 0
    var imageList = List<CheckOutImageList>()
    @objc dynamic var remarks = ""
    @objc dynamic var isFollowUp = Bool()
    @objc dynamic var followDate = ""
    @objc dynamic var followTime = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "taskId"
    }
}
```

I can perform add and update operation on *CheckOutDetail* class but need help to add, update and delete in image list array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this problem I made some changes in my objects. What I did, I just create two separate objects for both *CheckOutDetails* and *CheckOutImageList* like below:

```
class CheckOutImageList: Object {

    @objc dynamic var taskId = 0
    @objc dynamic var imageUrl = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageName = ""
    @objc dynamic var isProfile = Bool()
    @objc dynamic var imageDesc = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "imageName"
    }
}

class CheckOutDetail: Object {

    @objc dynamic var taskId = 0
    @objc dynamic var remarks = ""
    @objc dynamic var isFollowUp = Bool()
    @objc dynamic var followDate = ""
    @objc dynamic var followTime = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "taskId"
    }
}

//Code to update old data or add new image data in the CheckOutImageList Object
if self.checkImageNameExist(imageName: imgDetail.fileName) {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(obj, update: true) //obj is of type CheckOutImageList
    }
} else {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(obj)
    }
}

//Function will return true if primary key already exist else return false
func checkImageNameExist(imageName: String) -> Bool {
    return realm.object(ofType: CheckOutImageList.self, forPrimaryKey: imageName) != nil
}
```

And use taskId in *CheckOutDetails* as a foreign key to fetch details of the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You can append `CheckOutImageList` element to the object `CheckOutDetail`.

Try this :

```
let realmIn = try! Realm()

var checkOutDetail = CheckOutDetail()
checkOutDetail.taskId = 1
checkOutDetail.imageList = "imageList"
checkOutDetail.isFollowUp = "isFollowUp "
checkOutDetail.followTime = "followTime"


// You can use for to append multiple elements to list
let newCheckOutImageList = CheckOutImageList()
newCheckOutImageList.imageUrl = "url"
nweCheckOutImageList.imageName = "imageName"
newCheckOutImageList.isProfile = "isProfile"
newCheckOutImageList.imageDesc = "imageDesc"

checkOutDetail.imageList.append(newCheckOutImageList)

try! realmIn.write {
     realmIn.add(checkOutDetail, update: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it does not fulfil my requirement. So What I did, I just create two separate objects one for CheckoutDetails and another for CheckOutImageList with a key taskId as a foreign key.

Comment: I don't thinks in this way realm DB works. Please add some code related to write operation to suggest any changes.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. I have updated some more code and its working well. If there is any better way then much appreciated.